# Trying to dynamically show divs based on dropdown selection -- works when switch case uses numbers as strings but not when used with numbers

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Ok so heres the issue. Im trying to get a web page to switch a panel between 1 of 3 choices based on a dropdown selection. Im trying to do this dynamically through javascript. The code is below.

Ive determined from setting up alerts that the function always hitting the default case and that the value being used as the switch expression is correct. the switch case is failing to switch. however, if i wrap the case values in quotes, it works. Why? the value is supposed to be an integer.

this is the function I'm running.

```
function switchPanels() {
        var e = document.getElementById("dpdSearch");
        var n = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
                alert("case 0, ");
                document.getElementById('divUsers').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divUsersActivity').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divPersonnel').style.display = "block";
                break;
            case 1:
                alert("case 1, ");
                document.getElementById('divUsersActivity').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divPersonnel').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divUsers').style.display = "block";
                break;
            case 2:
                alert("case 2, ");
                document.getElementById('divPersonnel').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divUsers').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('divUsersActivity').style.display = "block";
                break;
            default:
                alert("defaulted " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
        }
        alert("ran switch");
```

The html is as follows:

```
<select id="dpdSearch" style="vertical-align: bottom" onchange="switchPanels();">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Personnel</option>
            <option value="1">Users</option>
            <option value="2">User Activity</option>
        </select>


<div id="divSearchPanel" style="display: block; width: 95%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
            <div id="divPersonnel" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 95%; display:block">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlPersonnel" runat="server">
                    <div style="width: 250px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="ID:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbFN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblLName" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbLN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text="Pay Rate:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbPR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <input class="right" id="dtpkrSD" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <input class="right" id="dtpkrED" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $("#dtpkrSD").datepicker();
                                $("#dtpkrED").datepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <div id="divUsers" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 95%;display: none;">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlUsers" runat="server">
                    <div style="width: 250px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblUserID" runat="server" Text="User ID:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbUID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="User Name" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <div id="divUsersActivity" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 95%;display: none;">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlUsersActivity" runat="server">
                    <div style="width: 250px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblActivityID" runat="server" Text="Activity ID:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbActivityID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblIP" runat="server" Text="IP Address:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbIP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblFormAccessed" runat="server" Text="Form Accessed"
                            Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <input class="right" id="txbFormAccessed" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblDateOfActivity" runat="server" Text="Date of Activity"
                            Style=""></asp:Label>
                        <input class="right" id="dtpkrDOA" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $("#dtpkrDOA").datepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is not an integer.

```
 var n = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

In fact n is a string (DOMString), the string used as value for the "value" attribute of the option element. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option

```
 var n = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 n=1*n;//This is one of the many ways to convert it to int
```

Comment: I would suggest using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for it is clearer what you are trying to do if somebody else is reading the code.

`parseInt(n, 10);`

Comment: That's the reason for the comment in the code. As you know parseInt is not very performant and is not really necessary here (small decimal number). I'd have use bitwise shift (or even ~~), but I understand that those operations could seem "obscure" to many. Anyway, if someone had a doubt you made it clear :)

Comment: Ah! ok. . . every page i found on the net said and showed otherwise. . But this is good to know. Thank you for your help and support @miguel-svq

Comment: @miguel-svq True, however, a self documenting code is better than adding comments. Also, the performance in this case is not an issue, thus clarity can, and probably should, be chosen over efficiency. As it is often chanted around programmers and in SO itself - do not optimise prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some idea that may related to you issue, Then you might get good idea to resolve it.

If you try to do this what you will get;

```
 var x= "1";

    if(x == "1")
    {
     // it is true 
    }



if(x == 1)
   {
    // it is true
   }
```

but it is not correct 1 != "1", because it is different type, JavaScript use strict type checking system like

```
if( x === "1")
{
  // true
}

if(x === 1)
{
  // false 
}
```